# How can I repeat this numpy array within itself?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `z` of `shape` `(8,)`:

```
>>> z
array([-30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        ,
       -27703.12304688, -27703.15429688, -27703.70703125, -27703.67382812])
```

I would like to copy the values 7 more times while maintaining their positions, to create an `array` `zr` of `shape` `(8,8)` e.g.:

```
    >>> z
    array([-30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        ,
           -27703.12304688, -27703.15429688, -27703.70703125, -27703.67382812],
          [-30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        ,
           -27703.12304688, -27703.15429688, -27703.70703125, -27703.67382812]
            .........)
```

I've tried np.repeat() but this creates an array of `shape` `(64,)` and I would like `(8,8)`.

```
>>> zr = np.repeat(z, 8)
>>> zr
array([-30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        ,
       -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        ,
       -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        ,
       -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        ,
       -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        ,
       -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        ,
       -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        ,
       -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        , -30000.        ,
       -27703.12304688, -27703.12304688, -27703.12304688, -27703.12304688,
       -27703.12304688, -27703.12304688, -27703.12304688, -27703.12304688,
       -27703.15429688, -27703.15429688, -27703.15429688, -27703.15429688,
       -27703.15429688, -27703.15429688, -27703.15429688, -27703.15429688,
       -27703.70703125, -27703.70703125, -27703.70703125, -27703.70703125,
       -27703.70703125, -27703.70703125, -27703.70703125, -27703.70703125,
       -27703.67382812, -27703.67382812, -27703.67382812, -27703.67382812,
       -27703.67382812, -27703.67382812, -27703.67382812, -27703.67382812])
>>> zr.shape
(64,)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just `.reshape((8, 8))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`np.tile`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) with a list to return a a 2D array:

```
# tile improvement courtesy OP
np.tile(z, [8, 1])
```

---

If you want a read-only view, [**`np.broadcast_to`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) is quite fast:

```
np.broadcast_to(z, (8,)+z.shape)
```

Comment: Thanks, also I used `np.tile(z, [8, 1])` and that worked too

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
np.tile(z,8).reshape(8,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [278]: z = np.arange(4)
```

`repeat` without axis just replicates each element in the flat order

```
In [280]: np.repeat(z,4)                                                                               
Out[280]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

but that can be massaged into your desired array:

```
In [281]: np.repeat(z,4).reshape(4,4)                                                                  
Out[281]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])
In [282]: np.repeat(z,4).reshape(4,4).T                                                                
Out[282]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

If `z` is (1,n) then we can repeat on the first axis:

```
In [283]: np.repeat(z[None,:],4,0)                                                                     
Out[283]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

`np.tile` may be easier to use.  Internally it uses `repeat`.